# Executable while loop: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, executable

I'm trying to write a simple bash script to iterate over input parameters for an executable file. The file in question has two parameters.

The following script works, running the terminal in the directory that contains both the .sh file and the .exe file:

```
#!bin/bash
./exec 1000 1
```

However the following does not:

```
#!bin/bash
n=1
while [ $n -le 50 ]
do
    ./exec 1000 $n
    n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

but instead returns the errors

> script.sh: line 5: ./exec 1000 1: No such file or directory
>
> script.sh: line 5: ./exec 1000 2: No such file or directory

And so on. This means the loop is happening but I don't understand why it can't find the executable all of a sudden. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Copying and pasting your source works fine for me. It looks like you're trying to execute the whole line "./exec 1000 N" as a command; make sure there's no quoting or anything causing that.

Comment: It turns out it was a spelling error in the name of the executable... woops. I'll delete the question. I'm glad I asked anyway otherwise I probably wouldn't have found it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, once I fix the shebang line:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
while [ $n -le 50 ]
do
    ./exec 1000 $n
    n=$(( n+1 ))
done
```

The original version causes an error message about a bad interpreter, but that might be avoided if your working directory happens to be / when you run the script.

Comment: Worked for me when I was running it too, I copied it by hand and didn't notice the missing / in the shebang! Good call.